# Azure Service Bus - AutoRenewTimeout on messages for python client

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I was going through the documentation of service AutoRenewTimeout feature and came across this post on [Lock Renewal Policy on service-bus messages](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-autorenewtimeout).

It talks about **AutoRenewTimeout** feature, where a message gets locked for a period of time so that the subscriber can finish processing the message or message gets timed-out (unable to process the message under a given period of time) under which the message will be visible to other subscribers reading from the same subscription.

I was unable to find a this feature in the [Microsoft Azure SDK for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-servicebus).
I have gone through the source code and it only talks about [Manual renewal of the lock](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.servicebus.servicebusservice.html#azure.servicebus.servicebusservice.ServiceBusService.renew_lock_subscription_message) on a particular message.

My usecase is as follows

- I have to read and process messages from the servicebus.
- Dumpe those processed message in a database (MongoDB in my case)
- Message pushed to servicebus can be as high as 1 million events per hour (so its impossible to keep track as to when a given messages is going to be
  timed-out and fire manual renewal for for the same).
- All those processed messages are pushed to a temporary list.
- Whenever the above list grows beyond a particular threshold, do a bulk insert on DB

Here is what I have come up with. Its with out the lock renewal policy I was talking about. I just fire a delete when a message is processed.

```
class Event:
    def __read_subscription_message(self):
        try:
            message = self.bus_service.receive_subscription_message(
                self.topic_name, self.subscription_name, peek_lock=True)
            return message
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception("Exception occurred!!!")

    def start_listner(self, task_number=0):
        self.logger.info('Task: %s, started listening to service bus messages' % task_number)
        while True:
            msg = self.__read_subscription_message()
            if msg and msg.body is not None:
                self.currentBackOff = 0
                self.process_event(msg, task_number)
                gevent.sleep(0)

    def process_event(self, msg, task_number=0):
        try:
            if msg.body:
                # message = json.loads(msg.body.decode())
                message = self.deserialize_message_body(msg.body)
                custom_properties = msg.custom_properties
                # Business logic implemented................
                # After processing a message append this to a temp list. Make
                # an insert which length of this list reaches a given threshold
                # by calling "write_to_storage(self, task_number=0)"
                self.bulk_records.append(record)
                msg.delete()
            else:
                self.logger.info("Message received: %s, is of type: %s" % (msg.body, type(msg.body)))
            self.total += 1
        except DeSerializationException as e:
            self.logger.info("Not able to de-serialize message: %s" % msg.body)
            self.logger.exception(e)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception(e)

    def write_to_storage(self, task_number=0):
        # Write to DB
```

It works fine, but in case when my subscriber process gets killed, then all of those messages which are in my temporary bucket (which are not written to database) were lost. I wish to fire a manual "`message.delete()`" on the messages when they are written to the database. I think `AutoRenewLock` is the way to go as the max value of lock duration on a message is 5 min, which will not helpful in my case.

Thank you

Comment: This temporary list you mentioned above, does this get stored in RAM or some kind of persistent storage?

Comment: The temporary list is stored in RAM (its a simple list data structure in python). I think writing every record to a temp file (before writing it to db in bulk) is more cumbersome because I have to handle the events as soon as they come to avoid back-filling of the subscription, also if the processes gets killed in the middle then I am left with a corrupted file (because file was not properly closed) or something similar might happen.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.autolockrenewer?view=azure-python

Here's the AutolockRenewer Documentation for v7 of servicebus

Answer (score 0):

So you should not need to write the message in a temporary log. If you use peek lock and the lock expires the message should go back in the queue and be picked up next time around. If you use peek lock you need to call message.delete() which you do in your code, only then it should be deleted from the broker.
This .net sample shows how it is supposed to work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues.

For convenience:
// Complete the message so that it is not received again.
// This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).

await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

Also see here on how peek lock is supposed to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read

So unless you call msg.delete the message should not count as completed. Are you running multiple subscribers on the same subscription or topic?

Regardless as long as you don't call delete the messages should just go back to the queue and your next receive call will pick them up. If you fail to receive multiple times they might get dead lettered. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues

Please use  service bus explorer to see if you actually loose messages or if they just get back in the queue or get dead lettered:
https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases